# ruby code inside HAML file giving unexpected error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, haml

I am trying to parse a JSON object inside the HAML file but I am getting an unexpected error when I run my `Cucumber` tests but it works fine in real without the cucumber tests.
The error says:

> show.html.haml:109: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)

So from my controller I get `@non-matches` which contains active record objects and in those objects, it contains a JSON String which I need to parse and print on separate lines.

This is the code inside my HAML file:

```
- @non_matches.each do |response_instance, non_matching_attributes|
 - @t = JSON.parse(response_instance.allocated_staff).each_with_index do |staff , index|
    %li Allocated Staff ##{index+1}: #{staff}
```

Can someone please help me in with this problem?

Comment: can you try `li` line as `%li Allocated Staff "#{index+1}: #{staff}"`?

Comment: @jonsnow i forgot to mention that it actually works the way i want it to but all the Cucumber tests fail.